# Errai (GWT) compilation is too slow -- how to make is faster

Tags: java, maven, gwt

Tested on a 3.2 GHZ Quad Core machine with 4GB DDR3L, running GWT with the following commands takes a very long time:

#### First

`mvn gwt:devmode`

#### Second

`mvn war:exploded`

2-3 minutes for running dev mode, and another few minutes for compilation starts in the browser. It's almost 5 minutes for every run and test.

What Maven configuration could work to make the GWT compilation faster?

Comment: To confirm, are you re-running both commands every time you change anything in your IDE? At least in theory, with a proper setup, you should run both once, and then every time you edit any client code, simply refresh the page in the browser, but do not stop and restart the devmode.

Comment: Hi Colin nope, I only run it once, the succeeding development is quite fast with the new Maven plugin with GWT setup I have, I just want to make sure that the initial setup to be fast and quick also since I also have to run the maven commands when adding libraries or things that Super Dev Mode cannot handle without restart

Comment: You said "It's almost 5 minutes for every run and test." - was there a typo in this then? Yes, adding a dependency will mean restarting, but if you run dev mode from your IDE then other things like changing code in other modules won't be a problem.

Comment: I added more RAM and compilation has speed up I just want to optimize more to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can set it to build for one browser only. Add this to the modules '.gwt.xml' file:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
```

(Other user agents can be found here https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml)

Another optimisation is to let gwt use more than one core when building. When you 'GWT Compile', on the advanced under 'Additional compiler options' add:

```
-localWorkers -8
```

Or the amount of thread you want to use.

Lastly, if your project contains multiple modules, each with their own entry points. You do not have to rebuild each one of them every time. Only the one you are working on. I have a project with 15+ modules and only build one at a time unless I have made a change to shared data in another module.

It's just as easy to remove modules from the 'GWT Compile' as it is to add them.

With the above being used you will get a build time of between 5 and 15 seconds.

Comment: "a build time of between 5 and 15 seconds" for a decent sized app? I'd believe that for a HelloWorld or something a little more complex, but not something you'd spend more than a week building... Local workers: this may not apply depending on your machine - more threads dedicated may often result in a slower build. Additionally, the max useful worker count is the permutation count - nothing is parallelized except that.

Comment: As a module grows the build time increases. But yes, when there's no need to rebuild every module, then building a single one takes me upto 15 seconds (~2k lines of code) and that's without cutting back on browser support. I do have an i7 which helps.

Comment: @ColinAlworth what would be your suggestion?

Comment: @WLGfx rebuilds are not done per-module: gwt is a whole-world compiler, and it must consider all code in order to rebuild any. Once upon a time there was a ".gwtar" archive that stored parts of the compiled project, but it only saved a very small amount of precompile time, and did not help the permutation compilation at all.

Comment: I have a ThinkPad laptop with 3.5 GHZ Intel core processor with 12 GB RAM and the total time to finish the gwt:devmode is 109 secs (as I remember) plus the time  for SuperDevMode to compile is 17.9 secs

Comment: I don't build for SuperDevMode as I need to run my project directly on an apache server. This large project fully builds in over 3 minutes, but each module separately is very quick. I've had no problems only working on a single module build. The only time I need to add other modules to the build is when I've made a minor change to client or server code.